# Complex N columns Per x rows Transpose

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel dataset with a rows and 5 columns per row.

I need to transpose so that all data is in rows with just two columns:

each row must have Column 1 from the dataset in its column 1 and each of the columns 2-5 in the dataset as its column 2, when those are exhausted row 2 of the dataset is processed in the same way. This would result in each row in the dataset creating 4 rows in the transposed set.

To better explain I have added in some screenshots of what I mean.

[image: Dataset]

[image: transposed rows]

unfortunately i cannot access VBA or macros on our machines so it needs to be a formula.

Sorry posted before I'd completed the question:

I have tried using a variation of =row() and =column() to try to count columns and then move to the next row when column number is more than 5 but I'm struggling to work out the logic that would work.

I've also toyed with =index with the entire dataset as an array and use some calculations to give the function the pointers to the row and column to next display.

But as an array its pretty slow when dealing with 10,000 records (and I still haven't worked out what logic I would use).

Comment: If you have Excel 2010+, you can use `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform` in Excel 2016) and merely `unpivot` the columns 2-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with `Index`  and `Row`

In you unpivot sheet, use

`A1`

```
=INDEX(Source!$A:$A,INT((ROW()-1)/4)+1)
```

`B1`

```
=INDEX(Source!$B:$F,INT(ROW()-1)/4+1,MOD(ROW()-1,4)+1)
```